# Javascript : How to avoid addition of a new property in a function?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am a JS newbie, reading a book [Javascript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) for understanding. One of the code snippets I could see :

```
var myFunc = function param() {
...
...
};
myFunc.cache={};
```

This indicates a new property can be added by anyone outside the function body. Doesn't this  break encapsulation ? What if some other part of program keeps on adding new properties making my object creation bulky ? What if someone deletes/modifies properties defined by me ?

I don't know if I am right in calling this a "problem". But if it is, please help with an approach to avoid this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript never really had any options to secure your objects but starting in ECMAScript 5 you can now [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) an object.

```
var o = { a: 1, b: 2 };
Object.freeze(o);
console.log(o.a); // 1
o.a = 2;
console.log(o.a); // 1
```

There is also a new context known as strict mode where an error can be thrown.

```
function processObject(o) {
    "use strict";
    delete o.a; // throws a TypeError
}
```

Comment: If I don't use strict mode, would I be able to add/delete, even after freeze() ?

Comment: @WinOrWin - When not in strict mode the code will run but nothing will happen. So they can write `o.c = 3` as much as they want but `o` will still remain the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't this break encapsulation ?

Yes and no. If you use a closure, you can still have "private" variables in the sense that they cannot be accessed from outside of the object's functions as declared at instantiation time. Example:

```
var ObjectPrototype = function () {
   var privateVariable = "closure-scope value";
   var InnerPrototype = function () {
       this.getPrivate = function () { return privateVariable; };
   };
   return new InnerPrototype();
};
var myObject = new ObjectPrototype();
```

Because the `ObjectPrototype` returns a new instance of the `InnerPrototype`, and `privateVariable` exists only within the `ObjectPrototype` closure, there is no way to access `privateVariable` directly from the outside. The only way to get the value of it is through `myObject.getPrivate()`.

Note: Javascript passes objects and arrays by reference, so this method only truly protects simple values (unless you are careful to return clones instead).

> What if some other part of program keeps on adding new properties
>   making my object creation bulky ?

That is something that you'll just need to keep an eye on.

> What if someone deletes/modifies properties defined by me ?

Use the closure-scoping method I described above to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

New properties can be added at anytime but it is not necessarily a bad thing.  The ability to override implementations is very powerful.

Normally, you'll want to add methods, objects, etc to the functions prototype, so try

```
myFunc.prototype.cache = {};
```

Ultimately you'll want to follow something like the module pattern

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Using the module pattern will allow you to create "private" members with privileged access to data via the closures.