# Newbie query on dynamic addition of properties

Tags: javascript

This is a follow-up to my previous [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172119/javascript-how-to-avoid-addition-of-a-new-property-in-a-function/12172186). I have been trying some code since then :

```
var myFunc = function(){
    this.int1=1;
    var int2=2;
};
myFunc.int1=3;
myFunc.int3=4;

for(var name in myFunc){
    console.log('myFunc...'+name+'='+myFunc[name]);
};

var myFuncImpl = new myFunc();
myFuncImpl.int1=5;
for(var name in myFuncImpl){
    console.log('myFuncImpl...'+name+'='+myFuncImpl[name]);
};
```

And I get output as :

```
myFunc...int1=3
myFunc...int3=4
myFuncImpl...int1=5
```

I can't answer the following questions :

1. Why isn't **int2** visible as a property to myFunc ? It's still in myFunc's scope, right ? Where does this definition disappear ?
2. Why I am I able to over-write **int1**'s value outside function scope ? What if someone accidentally deletes my values outside code ? For "objects", I understand "Object.freeze()" can help over myFuncImpl - but what about function definitions like myFunc ?
3. Why can't I access **int3** from myFuncImpl ? Where did the prior definition (while defining myFunc) go ?

I guess my doubts are due to my thinking of myFunc as a "class" (as in Java) and myFuncImpl as an object. Perhaps I am straying too far ?

Thanks !

Comment: This link might answer some of your questions - http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `int2` is *effectively* a private variable, so code outside the function cannot detect it http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html
2. This is just a fact of life with "vanilla" JS. if you need to prevent overwriting values, implement with `Object.defineProperty`. Caveats with IE<9
3. `int3` is a 'static' property to the function. It is not available on the instance, sort of like in C# if you have a static method, it's not available to instances of the class. The difference here is you can later on in your code say `myFunc.int1 = "asdf";` and now your 'static' property has changed. Don't confuse **static** with **constant**
   http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/19/basic-javascript-part-7-static-properties-and-methods/