# Restrict javascript class instances to particular properties

Tags: javascript

I would like to define the structure of a class, and throw an error if the user attempts to set a property on one of my object instances using a property that is not defined in the class.

For example, say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.propertyA = 'A value';
    this.propertyB = 'Another value';
  }
}
```

And then when the user is modifying object instances...

```
let myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.propertyA = 'a new value'; // would work fine
myInstance.propertyC = 'unknown property value'; // throw exception
```

Is this possible? The [seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) keyword appears to be close to what I want. It would prevent new properties from being added, but I would like to throw exceptions in case the user type-o's the valid property names.

**Update:**
Using `Object.preventExtensions`, `Object.seal`, or `Object.freeze` in strict mode will cause errors when a non-existent property is assigned to an object.

Comment: Perhaps something like Typescript, which gives you static type checking and can issue warnings at compile time, is more useful than a runtime check here?

Comment: You can make use of getters/setters

Comment: Related: [Javascript : How to avoid addition of a new property in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172119/javascript-how-to-avoid-addition-of-a-new-property-in-a-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `Proxy` to intercept new property additions and prevent new properties from being defined:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.propertyA = 'A value';
    this.propertyB = 'Another value';
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: (_, prop) => this[prop],
      set: (_, prop, value) => {
        if (!(prop in this)) throw new Error('Prop does not exist!');
        this[prop] = value;
      }
    });
  }
}

let myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.propertyA = 'a new value'; // would work fine
console.log('about to set propertyC:');
myInstance.propertyC = 'unknown property value'; // throw exception
```

A much terser method that prevents new properties from being added is to use `Object.preventExtensions()`. Attempts to add new properties will throw an error in strict mode:

```js
'use strict';
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.propertyA = 'A value';
    this.propertyB = 'Another value';
    Object.preventExtensions(this);
  }
}

let myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.propertyA = 'a new value';
console.log('About to add propertyC');
myInstance.propertyC = 'unknown property value';
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track! For my needs, `Object.preventExtensions` in combination with strict mode got the desired behavior.

Comment: Just to be clear: The `Object.preventExtensions` method WILL cause an exception if you are running in strict mode.